# "Substract" folder from another one (reverse copy)

Tags: bash, copy

I copied some files from a folder to another folder using the command `cp -R ~/foo/* /`

Now I want to undo this. I know this is possible, but what would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: In general, this is not possible to reverse.  What if you've overwritten something with the same name?

Comment: I can tell you I haven't overwritten any files.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
for f in `ls src`
do
    rm "dst/$f"
done
```

Watch out for icky filenames with whitespace in them though.

Comment: Therefore (to avoid whitespace problems), use `for f in src/*`, and `rm "dst/${f#src/}"`.